# Html marquee tag

Tags: html

Is html marquee tag deprecated ?
If yes what are the alternatives for it on the modern browser ?

I want to create a simple marquee effect on my joomla page

Comment: why on earth would you wanna use `marquee`? If you want a cool effect, use some jQuery (like Easing Plugin: http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

Comment: ...or to put it the other way round: If your design explicitly needs an marquee, why are you bothered with validation?

Comment: I want to show a set of sliding images how do i do that

Comment: Javascript will allow you to do that, but I strongly suggest that you either: A) Start a new question asking specifically how to do a sliding image effect, or B) Edit this question to ask that. Any question about the marquee tag will draw a lot of flack and obscure the real question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has been deprecated. You'll probably have to use javascript, implementing it with a jQuery UI effect should be straightforward. Check out this demo, I think this is what you are after:
http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/

Answer (score 13):

> Is html marquee tag deprecated ?

No, it would have had to been part of the language in the first place before it could be deprecated.

It is simply proprietary.

> If yes what are the alternatives for it on the modern browser ?

The best option is: Nice, easy to read motionless test.

Scrolling text is excellent for displaying a lot of information, in a small space, non-interactively.

Web browser windows are neither small, nor non-interactive (we have scrollbars), so the benefits of scrolling text are lost and you are left only with the drawbacks (which are that it is harder to read, and distracting when users are trying to read other parts of the page).

The only standard way to achieve scrolling text (if you still want it, despite the horrible drawbacks) is to use JavaScript to dynamically change CSS to move an element about.

Comment: I do not want to scroll text, i want to scroll a table of images !!
An suggestions on that

Comment: Almost all the problems of scrolling text apply equally to scrolling images. The methods to implement them are also the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can use javascript and CSS to generate nice looking elements which will have the functionality of a marquee.

You can have a loot at **[11 Obsolete features - HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/obsolete.html#the-marquee-element)**

**[jScroller](http://jscroller.markusbordihn.de/)** is an autoscroller in jQuery

Comment: I like the concept of "having a loot at" something; please don't correct it!

Answer (score 1):

Marquee tag is deprecated by [w3c](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_tag), there is no such tag in [HTML Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/elements.html). 
So you should not use this tag at all. In case you need functionality of this tag you should use some jquery plugin, i.e

- http://jscroller.markusbordihn.de/
- http://plugins.jquery.com/project/marquee
- http://www.givainc.com/labs/marquee_jquery_plugin.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to generate the ticker effect.

Tutorial
http://www.pagecolumn.com/webparts/ticker.htm

Demo
http://www.pagecolumn.com/webparts/ticker_bbc.htm

Answer (score -1):

Use Below Jquery:-

```
https://www.givainc.com/labs/marquee_jquery_plugin.cfm
```

**Requirement:**

```
jQuery v1.2.6 (or higher)*
jquery.marquee.js Plug-in
```