# Blink a label inside a repeater control

Tags: asp.net, .net, label, repeater

I have a label in a ItemTemplate in a Repeater control. I want the text of the label to blink on certain conditions. How do I do that? I am using ASP.Net 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

As the `<blink>` tag is long time obsolete and officially dead you can use the jQuery [blink plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/blink).

However think twice before adding such a thing to live website, most people do not like blinking test. The tag was killed for a reason..

Comment: Maybe he could resurrect the old <marquee> tag too? Ewww... :)

Comment: @jesus lol! Just in case.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227815/html-marquee-tag ;-)