# Marquee is not working fine in firefox (I am using many jQuery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a website there are many jQuery scripts used including parallax:

```
jquery.parallax.js  
jquery.anythingslider.fx.js  
jquery.anythingslider.js
```

etc there are still many more :

There are `<div>` for left side and right side contents. In the left side `div` I have used `img` tag only and in right side `div` tag there are galleries and many more things. Now on top of the right side I am using a marquee, but it's not working in Firefox and working fine in other browsers. Now I am using `marquee` tag, this tag is working fine in Chrome and other browsers but in Firefox this is not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Check this http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/ and this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6905/jquery-marquee-without-flickering-less-memory-consumption-and-no-plugin

Comment: Check this one of my old replies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547797/very-simple-very-smooth-javascript-marquee ; Marquee was annoying and its never deprecated as it was never been part of the language **If you keen** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227815/html-marquee-tag

Answer (score 3):

The `marquee` tag has been deprecated. Firefox no longer supports it. Instead you need to use some javascript or a jQuery plugin if you would like to scroll text across the screen.

*Edit by Tatsinnit* Thanks Rory for permission.

`marquee` is the non-standard HTML element. So I reckon there will be information around must be divided amongst 2 sects:

- Deprecation Sect - read this: [Html marquee tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227815/html-marquee-tag) Quentin's reply in particular 4rth post from top.
- Unfollowed - Information that it was a non-stadard tag so there is no point of deprecation.

`<marquee>` was first introduced by Microsoft and then other browsers extended their support [1].

Further please take a look into the mozilla page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/marquee for any further read if you are keen.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element

[2] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: Yo bruv `:)` check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547797/very-simple-very-smooth-javascript-marquee

Comment: Thanks bruv ++1 to you, but is it true that Marquee was never been the part of the language

Comment: From which version of Firefox, `marquee` tag has been deprecated? Does it supports in `FireFox 17`?

Comment: @JustinJohn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/marquee will throw some light bruver! also its a non-standard `:))`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan may I have your permission to change or rather add few stuff in your post please? `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit: From Answer `Firefox no longer supports it.` While I tested it in `FF17`, it works great. It is deprecated by the W3C and not advised by them for use in any HTML documents. But if we discard there advice it can be still used. Firefox still supports it.

Comment: @JustinJohn The Answer is further updated bruv `:)` take a look, `marquee` is non-standard html tag. its nice read and links included are good read as well, thanks for the comment bruv! have a nice one! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

the marquee is deprecated, so you need to use javascript (there is a jQuery plugin i think) or you can use ccs3 (if target browser supports it)