# Marquee doesnot scroll smoothly, need 100% smooth scroll for marquee

Tags: html

I am using marquee scroll from right side to the left. The below code works fine. But its not scrolling smoothly. The content "Hover on me to stop" is blinking or flashing. I need a 100% smooth scroll for the below marquee. Please help me. Whether it is possible without javascript??

```
<marquee behavior='scroll' direction='left' scrollamount='3' onmouseover='this.stop()' onmouseout='this.start()'>Hover on me to stop</marquee>
```

Comment: marquee tag has been deprecated. please do not use. see this for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2227838/1121982

Comment: How much will you pay? If you're not paying I understand you wanna do it by yourself. Just [Google](http://www.google.com) "javascript marquee alternative"

Comment: What they said. Also, they forgot to mention that your marquee does not blink or flash. It works as expected, 100% smooth.

Comment: Just do not use deprecated tags. We're not in the 90's anymore. Find a modern solution to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to try it using pure CSS then this is the easiest approach. Though you need to check the support for older browsers and do add vendor prefixes.

```css
.marquee-parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
}
.marquee-child {
  display: block;
  width: 147px;
  /* width of your text div */
  height: 30px;
  /* height of your text div */
  position: absolute;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite; /* change 5s value to your desired speed */
}
.marquee-child:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
  cursor: pointer;
}
@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    left: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -147px /* same as your text width */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee-parent">
  <div class="marquee-child">
    Hover on me to stop
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

A little late to the party..

There's an angular directive for this: https://github.com/davidtran/angular-marquee. You don't touch any js - just add the directive tag and you're done

```
<div angular-marquee></div>
```

And it doesn't fall back on the "deprecated tag" argument, relying on modern solution