# Marquee images with caption

Tags: html, css

I wanted to know if there was a simple css/html only method to solve this issue.
I am creating a `marquee` of images, inside a `div` of fixed width. The images inside this are many, i.e. they overflow the `div` easily. The simple `marquee` over this set of images is simple, and by default works well. The overflow images are simply shown in turn.
    `<marquee>`
    `<img ..... />`
    `<img ..... />`
    `<img ..... />`
    `</marquee>`

But i want a caption, i.e. image name below each image. The problem I'm facing is, when I try to add this using simple markup or CSS, instead of having images `marquee` in a single line, the ones that overflow the `div` without `marquee` wrap below the first images. This means, the more the images(outside `div` in standstill), the more number of rows.

I've tried enclosing each image in a separate div each, writing below the image. Also, using multiple `span` elements with display block and fix width equal to image width, for each image, i.e. a separate line of text under images to go along.
Also, I've tried using `HTML5` tags of `<figure>` and `<figcaption>`, but every time, same problem arises in a way or other.

If there is any possible solution to this using only HTML and CSS, please suggest. 
P.S. This page is static.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this might be tough without a working sample or more code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `marquee` element is a [proprietary tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227815/html-marquee-tag), a bad pratice for HTML4 and HTML5. W3C says that HTML is just for markup, not for formatting or animations. You could try one of those options, both according to web standards:

**JavaScript or jQuery**

Use a [slider script](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-animation-advanced-marquee/) with Javascript or jQuery.

**CSS3**

Create a marquee animation using [CSS3](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-animation-advanced-marquee/).

Comment: actually, this still doesn't address my issue. The issue is with using HTML/CSS only. I know many javascript or jquery libraries exist.

Comment: As I said `marquee` is not a good option. You should study CSS3 animation tho.

Answer (score -3):

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<marquee direction="left"><table><tr><td style="min-width:250px;"><img src="images/img1.png"  alt="" style="width:155px;height:79px;" /><img src="images/img2.png"  alt="" style="width:155px;height:79px;" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</br></br><span style="padding-right:20%;">Add tittle-1 here</span><span style="padding-right:20%;">Add tittle-2 here</span></td></tr></table></marquee>
</body>
</html>
```