# HTML marquee change behaviour

Tags: php

If I put marquee in `while` loop it shows all the data at the same time, sliding right to left. I want this to behave one by one, when one finishes the second starts... and lastly the first comes again, how can I do this please help me out I would be very grateful to you, thanks in advance :)

```
$data=mysql_query("SELECT heading from moto_static_pages");
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){ 
  echo '<marquee  behavior="scroll" direction="left" style="padding:0 0 10px 0;">';
  echo $res['heading'];
  echo '</marquee>';
}
```

Comment: Try to put the $data into an array, and iterate through it, with foreach loop

Comment: Using Marquee?!? What decade are you living in? the 1990's still?

Comment: @MarkBaker rather than insulting Amy, how about referring her to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227815/html-marquee-tag

Comment: @MarkBaker if anyone demands to use it you cant refuse it can you? :)

Comment: @Amy Could you mark an answer as correct by 'ticking' it then? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is **server-side**. Everything is computed on the server, and then all at the same time displayed on the browser in-front of you. So your loop is merely looping around what eventually *will* be displayed in the browser, and printing it all out at once, which is what it's supposed to do.

You will need to use JavaScript to accomplish this, as this *is* client-side. You cannot do this with PHP.

You will need to retrieve all the data from your database, convert it to json (`json_encode()`), and send this to your browser as one string. Then, in **JavaScript**, loop through the json and print out each one as a marquee with a timed event.

To reiterate, unless you are going to be doing something with asynchronous I/O with PHP, which you **aren't**, you will need to do this with **JavaScript**.

---

> This is *untested* code and straight from the top of my head, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

```
<?php

// Server-side code, get your data, json encode it too!

$data = json_encode(mysql_query("SELECT heading from moto_static_pages"));

?>

<script type = "text/javascript">

    // Client side code that happens in real time in the browser

    // Get your data from your php variable
    var data = JSON.parse(<?php echo $data; ?>);

    // Loop your data
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        // Output your data in marquees
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.write("<marquee behaviour='scroll' direction='left'>");
            document.write(data[i].heading);
            document.write("</marquee>");
        }, 4000); // Every 4 seconds
    }

</script>
```

Don't expect this code to just work for you, so get debugging it and using `var_dump()` to see what you get from PHP, and `console.log()` to see what you have in JavaScript.

**Final Note**

`mysql_query` has been deprecated and should be used with caution. You should check out `PDO` / `mysqli` instead; they're not too hard to understand and they're interesting too!