# marquee works only on localhost?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I know marquee is a terrible tag to use but I guess it does the job for this particular part. I put a marquee tag on a text line and it works when I run it locally but when I upload it to my ubuntu server the text doesn't even show! Any ideas why? Or an alternative (in jquery) or something?

ps. I append the text in jquery.

html:

```
 <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount = "1" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" width = "50px" id="player_title_display"></marquee>
```

css:

```
#player_title_display {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 14px;
        height: 22px;
        width: 80px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 72.5px;

    }
```

Comment: Oh man! The marquee tag. I haven't seen one of these since 1999. Don't use this. You could use jQuery. I will put something together.

Comment: @realseanp Loading jQuery if he is not already using it would be a terrible idea.

Comment: @MrN00b You're right, but OP is already using jQuery to append the text. It seems like the issue here is not the `marquee` tag, but rather the paths to the resources being incorrect.

Comment: Aha, I missed that :).

Comment: How are you loading jQuery on your server? If you're appending the text via jQuery and the text isn't showing, it would make sense that jQuery isn't loaded. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @MrN00b in what case, then, is it *ever* appropriate to load jquery? everyone using jquery started somewhere. it's a good library for doing exactly what OP needs. there is not a great way to do this without using a library.

Comment: @sgroves I would say loading jQuery is appropriate when you are going to get multiple uses out of it. IMO, loading jQuery just to replace a `marquee` tag seems to be a bit overkill. I know that `marquee` is deprecated ([sort of...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227815/html-marquee-tag#answer-2228009)) but if OP were not using jQuery already, I'd rather use a deprecated tag than load an entire Javascript library just for the one purpose.

Comment: @drydenlong why though? you're just saying it's overkill without saying why. it's not 2002 - js libraries are cheap (in every respect) these days. using one just for scrolling text is perfectly fine. beats writing your own scroller or trying to support deprecated tags (*almost never* a good idea and usually a time waster). jquery is under 100 KB. it's possibly THE best solution for this. what's the problem?

Comment: @sgroves You're right, it's not 2002 and most household internet connections are capable of handling the bandwidth of jQuery, but what about mobile devices or people who live in rural areas and don't have broadband connections? Sometimes a person has shotty service and is loading pages via an EDGE connection. It's not a common problem, but for just the purpose of a `marquee`, I personally wouldn't load jQuery. Either way, it's a moot point since OP is already using jQuery for other purposes so they may as well use it for this.

Comment: @sgroves, ideally, every developer would rather use jQuery than a `marquee` tag, but there's absolutely nothing web users hate more than a minor improvement costing them an extra few seconds of waiting to load the page. I haven't looked at the data, but I would expect mobile browsing to be nearly as common as desktop browsing, and 4G isn't exactly wide-spread. I don't even get 3G the whole way to work.

Comment: The problem is not in the code posted. Since it works for you locally, the problem is in the version on the server, about which nothing has been disclosed. *Something* goes wrong there.

Comment: @everyone jquery is 100 KB!! that's *nothing* on ANY connection! a few extra seconds to load your page is also worth it, regardless, to make your page work well. fud, fud, fud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jquery alternative since you have asked one. You can find more details [here](http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin#examples). Your HTML markup as below

```
<div class="marquee">Your marqueee text goes here </div>
```

and your css

```
.marquee {
width: 300px;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background: #ccc;
}
```

and you reference the plugin as

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.3.1/jquery.marquee.min.js'></script>
```

and finally your js function `$('.marquee').marquee();`

Comment: Thanks @IanMustafa for putting this together in a demo.