# Marquee lagging in safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, marquee

We are using a Marquee tag in on our site. 
But when we was bug testing it, it was lagging in safari on phone. Is there a sulution to reduce the lag? It is working fine in Chrome.

Comment: marquee tag has been deprecated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227815/html-marquee-tag use css3 instead

Comment: I was thinking nobody was using marquee anymore, i was wrong... :)

Comment: A simple alternative would be to use CSS3 animation  http://jsfiddle.net/0dyhha3z/

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<marquee width="350" direction="left" scrollamount="3" behavior="scroll"><p>START Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet END</p></marquee>
```