# marquee tag not working on hover effect in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have used marquee tag. this tag of hover effect working good in Mozilla but not working hover effect in google chrome. I have tried this solution.

```html
<marquee direction="up" height="250px" onmouseover="javascript:this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 6, 0);">
  
  text
  </marquee>
```

Please suggest any other solution.

Comment: Why you still use `marquee`? it is deprecated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227815/html-marquee-tag

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of it:

```
onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();"
```

```html
<marquee direction="up" height="250px" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
  
  text
  </marquee>
```

Comment: What's your chrome version? i test on FF and chrome it's working good. @user5803787

Answer (score 0):

If anyone get same problem so please use this solutions,

```html
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="up" onMouseOver="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);this.stop();" OnMouseOut="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 2, 0);this.start();" scrollamount="2"> hellow world </marquee>
```